# Remove full path from terminal

Tags: 12.04, command-line, home-directory

Is it possible to show in the terminal line only the current directory, not the whole path from the home folder?

I have now this: `ilya@ubuntu:~/Dropbox/Web/folder/folder/$` and it takes almost all the screen...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The part before the $ in a shell is called prompt. It can be configured by changing the variable `$PS1`. There are is a [similar question with good answeres](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114227/shell-prompt-customization).

The man page (see "Bash" and there "PROMPTING") says:

```
      \w     the  current working directory, with $HOME
             abbreviated with a tilde (uses the value of the
             PROMPT_DIRTRIM variable)
      \W     the basename of the current working directory,
             with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde
```

So you have to change `\w` to `\W`. Probably the initial value for $PS1 is stored in your `.bashrc`, that means you have to edit the file `~/.bashrc` and you will find lines similar to:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Change `\w` to `\W` in both lines and open a new terminal (or run `source ~/.bashrc)`.